# Asynchronous JavaScript doesn't let my function return?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, asynchronous

This may be a very easy and novice question, and I'm not even sure if the asynchronous call is the one to blame. But anyway...

I'm using jQuery and its function to add external scripts on a .php file.
First, let's have a look at my external js. (test.js):

```
function testFunc () {
  alert('It works!');
}
```

Then I have my .php file with this script:

```
<script>
$.getScript('supervisor/cache/test.js');
$(document).ready(function() {
  testFunc();
});
</script>
```

Using this method, the `testFunc();` is not called. I tried inserting `return` before the call, putting it outside the `ready` function, putting the `$.getScript` inside the `ready` function. Well, I don't know what else to try.
Also, if I call this same function using the `onClick` in a button, it will work.
That's why I think the problem may be with the Asynchronous call from jQuery, that is executing my function before the script is *really* added. But who knows? Anyone had the same problem before?

Comment: @tylermwashburn: I assumed he outputs that script via PHP as part of the website.

Comment: @tylermwashburn I think that he meant that the JavaScript shown is *produced* by the .php code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should invoke the function once the AJAX script has finished executing which could happen much later than the document ready event:

```
$.getScript('supervisor/cache/test.js', function() {
    testFunc();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are retrieving the script asyncronously, the document is probably ready before test.js is loaded.  Do this instead:

```
$.getScript('supervisor/cache/test.js', function(){
    testFunc();
});
```

Comment: same as @darin.  he and I must have been writing our answers at the same time.

Comment: So you also deserve a +1, as this is not the Wild West where the fastest hand wins :)